# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\adminController::editpost(), 1 passed in on line 54 and exactly 2 expected

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8

I want to update data in my database but this error popped up after I pressed submit. I have been searching for this problem and it is still not solved.

This is my Controller

```
public function editpost($id, Request $request){
        $data = Difabels::find($id);
        $data->barang = $request->barang;
        $data->pemilik = $request->pemilik;
        $data->tanggal = $request->tanggal;
        $data->wa = $request->wa;
        if ($request->opsi1 !=null){
            $data->opsi1_check =1;
        }
        if ($request->opsi2 !=null){
            $data->opsi2_check =1;
        }
        if ($request->opsi3 !=null){
            $data->opsi3_check =1;
        }
        if ($request->opsi4 !=null){
            $data->opsi4_check =1;
        }
        if ($request->image !=null){
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $nama_file = date('YmdHi').$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $tujuan_upload = 'data_file';
            $file->move($tujuan_upload,$nama_file);
            $data->image = $nama_file;
        }
        $data-> update();


        return redirect('/admin/overview');
    }
```

This is my Route

```
Route::post('/update/post', [\App\Http\Controllers\adminController::class, 'editpost'])->name('admin.editpost');
```

I have prefix /admin for this

This is my blade.view

```
<form action="{{route('admin.editpost', ['id'=>$data['id']])}}"method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="">
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you. Sorry for my bad grammar

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? How is this error related to MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

The route path parameter `id` is missing. The route definition should be like this:

```
Route::post('post/{id}/update', [\App\Http\Controllers\adminController::class, 'editpost'])->name('admin.editpost');
```